# How do I install pydb in OS X

Tags: python, macos, debugging

I would very much like to use pydb, however, there does not seem to be any cut-and-dry explanation of how exactly I can go about installing it on OS X.

I am surprised that there is no homebrew formula for it. Is there any particular reason why there isn't a formula?

I do not want to use MacPorts, becuase I already have homebrew installed.

EDIT:
`pip install pydb`
fails

Comment: Pydb looks like a massively out-of-date project which hasn't been updated in over 5 years and isn't compatible with any recent release of Python. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: what about `pip install pydb` ?

Comment: To answer the above two comments: 1. I am familiar with gdb, and it seems that pydb makes use of similar syntax. As far as it being out of date, yeah, that doesn't seem great, but I'm having trouble finding alternatives.